# Format data in javascript

Tags: javascript, format

I am trying to format data for a multi-line chart. I want to format the data based on the Internal and External and also need to add total which is the sum of Internal and External. Need help with the formatting. Thanks in advance!

The sample data is as below:

```
[
 {
"date": "2021-02-09",
"value": 1,
"user": "Internal"
},
{
"date": "2021-02-09",
"value": 1,
"user": "External"
},
{
"date": "2021-02-12",
"value": 2,
"user": "Internal"
},
{
"date": "2021-02-12",
"value": 1,
"user": "External"
},
{
"date": "2021-02-14",
"value": 0,
"user": "External"
},
{
"date": "2021-02-14",
"value": 2,
"user": "Internal"
}
]
```

My required output should be:

```
[
{
"date" : "2021-02-09",
"Internal": 1,
"External": 1,
"Total" : 2
},
{
"date": "2021-02-12",
"Internal": 2,
"External": 1,
"Total": 3
},
{
"date": "2021-02-14",
"Internal": 2,
"External": 0,
"Total": 2
}
]
```

Comment: What did you try so far? And why didn't it work?

Answer (score 2):

Can be done easily using `reduce`

PS: Please also provide your attempt when you ask questions here. It'll help us help you better. Thanks

```js
var input = [{
    date: "2021-02-09",
    value: 1,
    user: "Internal"
  },
  {
    date: "2021-02-09",
    value: 1,
    user: "External"
  },
  {
    date: "2021-02-12",
    value: 2,
    user: "Internal"
  },
  {
    date: "2021-02-12",
    value: 1,
    user: "External"
  },
  {
    date: "2021-02-14",
    value: 0,
    user: "External"
  },
  {
    date: "2021-02-14",
    value: 2,
    user: "Internal"
  }
];

var output = input.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  var existingIndex = (acc || []).findIndex(
    (entry) => entry.date === curr.date
  );
  if (existingIndex !== -1) {
    // Only update the entry
    acc[existingIndex].value += curr.value;
    acc[existingIndex][curr.user] += curr.value;
  } else {
    // Insert new entry
    acc.push({
      date: curr.date,
      Internal: curr.user === "Internal" ? curr.value : 0,
      External: curr.user === "External" ? curr.value : 0,
      value: curr.value
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over data like this and filter out the dates and the internal external counts based on your calculations in a new array

```
const sampleData = [{
    "date": "2021-02-09",
    "value": 1,
    "user": "Internal"
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-09",
    "value": 1,
    "user": "External"
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-12",
    "value": 2,
    "user": "Internal"
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-12",
    "value": 1,
    "user": "External"
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-14",
    "value": 0,
    "user": "External"
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-14",
    "value": 2,
    "user": "Internal"
  }
];

let formattedData = [];

sampleData.forEach(item => {
  const itemIndex = formattedData.findIndex(newItem => newItem.date === item.date);
  const internalCount = item.user === "Internal" ? item.value : 0;
  const externalCount = item.user === "External" ? item.value : 0;
  if (formattedData.length === 0 || itemIndex === -1)
    formattedData.push({
      date: item.date,
      internal: internalCount,
      external: externalCount,
      total: internalCount + externalCount
    });
  else {
    formattedData.splice(itemIndex, 1, {
      date: item.date,
      internal: formattedData[itemIndex].internal + internalCount,
      external: formattedData[itemIndex].external + externalCount,
      total: formattedData[itemIndex].total + internalCount + externalCount
    });
  }
});

console.log(formattedData);
```